# Scrolling functionality in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

In my application I want to provide functionality of scrolling entire layout on screen. Here i also wrapped Linearlayout within the ScrollView, but it doesn't provide scrolling facility.
The following is my layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    >

<LinearLayout  
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:paddingTop="50dp"
  android:weightSum="1"
  android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
  >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/artistImageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:background="#000000"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BIOGRAPHY"
        android:textColor="#eeeeee"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
    />          
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/separator_bio"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:background="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/sep1"
    />                  
    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/artistView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"              
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"        
        android:background="#000000"
    />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Please suggest solution.Thanx.

Comment: Is the content height enough? It will not enable scrolling if the content fits the screen.

Comment: the Textview - "artistView" will display artist biography information which is lengthy content.Thus, it should provide scrolling functionality to display whole content.But it just show half content and doesn't allow scrolling.

Comment: Will or does? You could try setting one view with a fix height of 800 (or something that will definitively trigger the ScrollView) and see if it scrolls then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final code which worked for my application.

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="163dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    >   
<LinearLayout  
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="250dp"
  android:orientation="vertical"  
  >
  <TextView android:id="@+id/artistName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="16px"
  />
  <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/artistImageView"   
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="150dp"        
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="100dp"
        android:background="#000000"

        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"

  />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BIOGRAPHY"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"

        android:background="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
    />          
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/separator_bio"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:background="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/sep1"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    />        

    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/artistView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#eeeeee"              
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"                       
        android:background="#000000"                        
        android:lines="25"
      android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"  

    />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest changing the content height in the linear layout to wrap_content

```
<LinearLayout  
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:paddingTop="50dp"
   android:weightSum="1"
   android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
   >
```

the reason for wrap content is that this way the scroll view will fill the screen and the linear layout is free to overflow. This overflow is what you would be scrolling through

**EDIT:**

after looking at your code more you don't actually need the `android:weightSum="1"` line since you never use weight to define any of the children's height. Also when using wrap_content there will never be left over room in a parent view so weight won't work quite like you expect it to :)

Answer (score 0):

Your above code is work for me means Scrolling is working in your above code from my side.

If your side this code not working than Try this.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"

  >
<ScrollView

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    >

<LinearLayout  
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:paddingTop="50dp"
  android:weightSum="1"
  android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
  >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/artistImageView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:background="#000000"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BIOGRAPHY"
        android:textColor="#eeeeee"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/txt1"
    />          
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/separator_bio"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
        android:background="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/sep1"
    />                  
    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/artistView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"              
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"        
        android:background="#000000"
    />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```